# I have four html textbox. Display minimum value in other textbox

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am new in java Script /ajax

I have four html textbox. Display minimum value in other textbook.If any text box has no value then no need to compare with other text box value.Just only compare who obtain the value.
If i change any text box value then automatically compare with new value and if find minimum value then then change the other text box value.

Actually i have to insert text box value and also the minimum value in other column in same table at same time.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function maximum() { 
        a=Number(document.addProduct.pPrice1.value); 
        b=Number(document.addProduct.pPrice2.value);
        c=Number(document.addProduct.pPrice3.value);
        D=Number(document.addProduct.pPrice3.value);
        m=Math.min(a,b,c,d);
        document.addProduct.result.value=m;  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should post what you have tried, what you are having issues with.

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function maximum(){

 a=Number(document.addProduct.pPrice1.value);

 b=Number(document.addProduct.pPrice2.value);

 c=Number(document.addProduct.pPrice3.value);
 
 D=Number(document.addProduct.pPrice3.value);
 
 m=Math.min(a,b,c,d);

document.addProduct.result.value=m; 

}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

> probably it might help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function maximum(){ 
   var a=document.getElementById("1").value; 
   var b=document.getElementById("2").value;
   var c=document.getElementById("3").value;
   var d=document.getElementById("4").value;
   var m=Math.min(a,b,c,d);
   document.getElementById("5").value=m;  
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="1"/>
<input type="text" id="2"/>
<input type="text" id="3"/>
<input type="text" id="4"/>
<input type="button" onclick="maximum()" value="MIN"/>
<input type="text" id="5">
```